# Is there existing functionality to search through a JSON object and replace values

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way we could check a json object for empty strings for each of its value and replace it as null? 
Looking for any existing solution that might exist in Spring preferably. I could of course loop over these and check then one by one and replace empty strings with null but prefer not to. This same object is used in other places where I will not be doing this replacement thus I don't want to change this. Thus I can't take the route of @JsonSerialize and writing a custom JsonSerializer. Instead is there some existing functionality where I could pass in my object which gets validated / allows me to set empty strings to null? Please advice how I could achieve this. Thanks.

Object Structure

```
    {
    "name": "a",
    "id": 1,
    "stuff": {
        "name": "b",
        "color": "red"
    },
    "others": [{
            "name": ""  // For example since this is empty, I want to replace this as null. 
        },
        {
            "name": " item2"
        },
        {
            "name": " item3"
        },
        {
            "name": " item4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Object Classes. Trying to find a solution to be able to just pass in the Response object.

```
public class Other {
    private String name;
}

public class Response {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private Stuff stuff;
    private List<Other> others;
}

public class Stuff {
    public String name;
    public String color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different JsonSerializers as per requirements.
If empty strings needed to be null in one place, Have such serializer customized accordingly.

Libraries such as Objectmapper supports this easily.